# How did Rey find this structure intact?

Tags: star-wars, continuity, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the end of *Rise of Skywalker*, Rey revisits a location we haven't seen since Episode IV,

> Uncle Owen & Aunt Beru's farmstead

which had previously been attacked.  Obviously, the attack is long past, and any remains were long removed.

That said, the structure was a well-known one and not in an untravelled area (as evidenced by the older woman Rey encounters just outside the structure).

This structure had at least moderate economic value and stood in a very harsh environment, which (on Earth, at least) tends to reclaim abandoned structures very quickly

> burying them in windblown sand, as anyone familiar with Egyptology can tell you

As a result, I'd expect someone else to have either taken over the property

> To continue running the moisture farm

or for it to have been reclaimed by the surrounding environment.

It is also significantly less on fire than I recall seeing it when Luke last left.

How did this happen?  Did Rey use the Force to uncover it?  Did Rey drive off and/or slaughter the new residents?  Did Ben's ghost busy himself dusting for a few decades?

Comment: Surely it *had* been reclaimed by the environment? It was half buried in sand, which Rey slides down.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The exterior was virtually identical to the shots of it in Episode IV (the buildings were *built* half-buried in the sand, likely to supplement the environmental controls) and the central area was very open and clean.  If you abandoned a well-made building at the edges of the Sahara desert for a year or two, it would be hard to find afterwards.

Comment: It was more buried than when lived in but not as much as you’d expect. Probably just for convenience.

Comment: No it was the central area I was talking about. That was clearly shown as half-buried, especially the vaporators in the middle, which it had not been in the originals. Again, the way Rey slides down the sand would not have been possible originally.

Comment: The property had electro-static repulsion to keep sand from getting into the property. Presumably it's still working (to some extent).

Comment: Do we ever actually see any wind on Tatooine? The wind is a major factor in sand reclaiming structures in desert environments here on earth; on a planet with little to no wind, the reclaim would be much slower.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine) shows a pretty high-dust environment. It would be hard to have such a scene without some wind.

Comment: I'm amazed how Javas didn't strip all those equipment down.

Comment: @EgeBayrak That's the REAL observation.  Those guys will take anything, even if it's motivators are bad. There's a lot of stuff there, and even if it's broken, they would likely take the parts and strip out any components still salvageable because that's what salvage scavengers do.

Comment: @Machavity: "Some wind" doesn't necessarily mean "sandstorms" though. Wind on Earth is produced largely by temperature differentials, particularly between land and water, and between land of varying elevations/composition (which absorbs sunlight differently). Tatooine is largely sandy desert, with some rocky wastes, but it's largely flat, and similar color, with no standing water. You'll get some wind off the rocky waste/sandy desert discrepancies, but nothing like what Earth's more varied surface produces. The Star Wars Databank link does claim it has sandstorms, but we've never seen one.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Do note that we actually have experience observing a sandy desert planet in real life: Mars, which does happen to have very large sandstorms. Obviously not an exact match for Tatooine, what with the extra sun and probably thicker atmosphere, but a decent indicator that huge variations in environments are not necessary for strong winds.

Comment: @8bittree: Good point.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Let's assume, for argument's sake, that Tatooine is just like Earth's sand-swept areas

## There's not a lot of things to naturally degrade the buildings

It's a desert, so you have naturally low humidity and probably no serious rainfall, two major things that destroy buildings fast. There's also no nearby mountains for runoff.

## Only 20-ish years have passed since it was abandoned

While there is *some* sand in the buildings, they're not totally subsumbed by sand. Consider the abandoned South African town of [Kolmanskop](https://www.businessinsider.com/kolmanskop-ghost-town-buried-in-sand-2015-10). It was abandoned around 1954, or about 65 years ago. While sand has infiltrated the buildings... they're really not in all that bad of a shape ([image source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jbdodane/))

[image: Kolmanskop]

## What about the moisture farm?

Well, the [moisture farm](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Moisture_farm) wasn't really tied to the land, but the air

> A moisture farm was an area of land devoted to the production of water through the drawing of moisture from the dry air.

I'm going off memory, but I don't recall seeing any of the [moisture vaporators](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Moisture_vaporator) near the abandoned house, which is the main thing you need form moisture farming. Those were almost certainly taken by scavengers. The house was likely not very valuable by itself, especially when you consider that it was remote, likely to help the Larses avoiding theft of the vaporators, or their household items. Remember that Luke had to use [his X-34](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/X-34_landspeeder) to get around.

## Where did the woman come from then?

Despite it being remote, there was probably a "road" that lead by there. My grandparents lived in a rural area where their nearest neighbor was half a mile away, but they still had a road. We see the Jawas come by to trade. The woman probably lived somewhere not too far off, but not close enough to be seen in any of the footage around the house.

Comment: Doesn't change the essence of your reasonable answer, but it has been at least 30 years in between

Comment: Interesting!  It seems that deserts' building reclamation is slower than i had believed.  Thanks for the insightful answer.

Comment: Definitely not 20-ish years, more like 40-ish. Just sayin'...

Comment: Moreover, the structure degraded at the speed of *plot*.

Comment: They could have used the original set--what's shown on screen is fairly close to the condition of the set, left in the middle of the desert in Tunisia

Comment: @MatthewBarclay If it hadn't had a makeover, yes. http://markdermul.be/savelars/photos6.html

Answer (score -3):

To be truth, we do not see if the house is occupied or abandoned.

As far as we know, the property could be reclaimed, someone could be living there and taking care of the structure.

Rey doesn't need to come and kill the residents, it just has to ask politely for permission to "pay her respects"

Comment: We see that the compound is full of sand, the electrics appear to be off and an old lady drops by to mention that no-one has lived there for a long time. I think we can be reasonably certain that the Lars Residence is unoccupied.

Answer (score -3):

It could be that, as a site associated with, literally, the savior of the galaxy, it has been left alone in reverence to its former occupant. A sort of shrine, if you will.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case. It's dilapidated and full of sand. Shrines are usually taken better care of

Comment: @Valorum I didn't say it was a shrine. I said it was like a shrine. Also, it's not that hard to find shrines here on earth that are dilapidated and full of sand, water, jungle vines, etc. There are also plenty of shrines on earth that no one takes care of.

Comment: Tatooine is in the middle of nowhere and not even part of the Empire. I would imagine that the average resident couldn't give one peggat for what happened to the Death Star or that a local boy was involved.

Comment: @Valorum I suggest that your imagination is as limited as your knowledge of shrines. The average resident of Tatooine most certainly knows about the local boy, not only because of his involvement in the Death Star, but also because of his involvement in eliminating the crimelord who reigned over the lawless planet.

Comment: I presume that a few minutes after Jabba's death, the other crime lords in the vicinity carved up his territory and things went on much as before for the average Tatooinian

Comment: @Valorum The one thing of which we can be certain is that afterwards, most of the planet knew what happened and knew who was responsible. Life for the average resident might change or it might not, but the local boy earned respect as a major player for taking out the big guy on Tatooine and that means you don't mess with him or and you don't mess with his home. That he took down even bigger guys ruling the galaxy just adds to his legend, and makes his home a place of reverence.

Comment: @Mohair: despite the upkeep (or lack thereof) of the shrines on Earth, it would stand to reason that if this location were supposed to be preserved as a historical site (or similar) there would be some sort of signage posted.  We see no evidence of this.

Comment: @Jeff Not far from where I live is the Spahn Movie Ranch. It was where the Manson Family hung out in 1968-69. It's not preserved as a historical site. There is nothing left there from that era. There are no signs. It's easily accessible but hardly anyone goes there. It's clearly visible from two nearby major roads. It's an unofficial historical site that all the locals know about. They will often point it out to visitors as they drive by. And that's my point. The people on Tatooine know what it is. They know who lived there. They know what he did. For that reason, they leave it alone.